# Event handling ignoring the param from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, events

So Im trying to make a simple form and make it send and email based on the information on the form. This is a sub window where you are supposed to receive the parameter from the URL (messages.aspx?mail=mail@mail.com). So far I am capturing the value from the mail and displaying it on the textfield.

But whenever I type another value and I hit on the button "Send", no matter if I do change the value on the textbox, it is only taking the value from the URL, completely ignoring the value on the box.

And if I open it by hand (messages.aspx), then add the email, of course, because there is no parameter in the URL, I just get the "Please add an email". I guess it is a event handling issue. But Im fairly new to this.

**Messages.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Messages : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public string emails = "";      
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loadList();
        emailT.Text = Request.QueryString["mail"];

    }

    protected void SendMail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BO.Messages mail = new BO.Messages();
        emails = Request.QueryString["mail"];
        if (emails != "")
        {
            emailT.Text = emails;
        }
        if(emailT.Text == "")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", "alert('Please fill in an email')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            mail.TemplateEmail(emailT.Text, title.Text, txtDetails.Text);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", "alert('Email sent!'); window.close()", true);
        }


    }
```

**Messages.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Messages.aspx.cs" Inherits="ASF.HC.JobApplication.Admin.Messages" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        #Button2 {
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Messages</h2>
    <br />  
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <legend>Pick the template to use:</legend>
    <asp:dropdownlist id ="ddlTemplate" runat ="server" Height="23px" Width="436px">
                  </asp:dropdownlist >     
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="Template_Changed" />
    <br /> <legend>Email Recipient: </legend>
                <asp:TextBox ID ="emailT" runat="server" Width="356px" Height="24px" Visible="true" Text="prueba@prueba.com"></asp:TextBox>
    <br /><legend>Email Subject: </legend><asp:TextBox ID ="title" runat="server" Width="356px" Height="24px" Visible="true" ></asp:TextBox>       
       <br />  <br /> <asp:TextBox ID ="txtDetails" runat="server" Width="850px" Height="267px" Visible="true" ></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDetails" 
                EnableSanitization="false" DisplaySourceTab="true" >
            </ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender><br />
    <br /><div align="center">
    <br />
        <legend>If you want to save the template, name it: (Optional) </legend><asp:TextBox ID ="nameTemplate" runat="server" Width="356px" Height="24px" Visible="true" ></asp:TextBox>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Send" Height="44px" Width="132px" OnClick="SendMail"/> <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Save Template" Height="44px" Width="132px" OnClick="saveTemplate"/>
    </div>
    <br />
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "not Postback" into the Page-Load Event and request the value from querystring only once, by Page-Load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) {
       loadList();
       emailT.Text = Request.QueryString["mail"];
    }
}

protected void SendMail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BO.Messages mail = new BO.Messages();

    if(emailT.Text == "")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", "alert('Please fill in an email')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            mail.TemplateEmail(emailT.Text, title.Text, txtDetails.Text);
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Redirect", "alert('Email sent!'); window.close()", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Added it, same issue. Apparently it is only considering the mail on the URL, so if I try **messages.aspx**, no matter what I type, I get, the "Please fill in an email". And if I try **messages.aspx?mail=mail@mail.com**, no matter what I type on the text form, it just chooses the one on the URL.

Comment: Sorry mate. I updated the function SendMail as well. You don't need to ask for the parameter twice. You do on page-load and after, you fetch the value inside the textbox.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked like a charm. Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

> But whenever I type another value and I hit on the button "Send", no matter if I do change the value on the textbox, it is only taking the value from the URL, completely ignoring the value on the box.

You're setting the value of the textbox to that of the query string in the page_load?

```
 emailT.Text = Request.QueryString["mail"];
```